# Consulta ao banco de dados em C# mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Como é a sintaxe ou como transformo uma query com vários joins para uma busca em minha aplicação em c# asp.net mvc?
Exemplo: Tenho um formulário com o seguinte controller

```
        public ActionResult Pesquisa(int id = 0)
    {

        var resultado = context.Graduacoes.Include(e => e.Cursos).Where(e => e.Id == id).ToList();

        ViewBag.Graduacoes = new SelectList(db.Graduacoes, "Id", "Nome");

      return View(resultado);
    }
```

Eu preciso que ao usuário selecionar na lista a graduação e clicar em 'Pesquisar' me retorne o nome e outras informações dos indivíduos que possuem aquela graduação. No banco eu faria assim:

```
select e.Id, c.Nome from Curso c
inner join Escolaridade e 
on e.Id = NívelId
```

Models

```
    public class Graduacao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O nome pode ter no máximo 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 20, ErrorMessage="O Nível deve ser um número positivo até 20.")]
    public int Nível { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}

    public class Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O Nome pode ter no máximo 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Instituição é obrigatória.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "A Instituição pode ter no máximo 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Instituição { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nível do curso é obrigatório.")]
    public int? NívelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Escolaridade Nível { get; set; }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<Competências.Models.Graduacao>
```

```
<title>Pesquisa por Graduação </title>
```

```
<div> 
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.DropDownList("Graduacoes")

    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
     }
</div>
<div>
<table>

    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
        <th>Nome </th>

    </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td width="30%">@item.Nome</td> 

           </tr>

            }
        }
    }
</table>
    </div>
```

Eu queria aqui, ao escolher uma graduação por exemplo "Ensino Médio" me retornar o nome de todos os cursos cadastrados com ensino médio. Eu quero retornar mais coisas, mas resumi para isso.

Answer (score 2):

> Aviso: essa resposta foi sendo desenvolvida a partir do que o autor da pergunta mencionou. Qualquer redundância ou detalhe esquisito que possa aparecer é pelas várias edições que esta resposta teve.

Estou supondo que tem um mapeamento assim na sua aplicação:

```
public class Graduacao
{
    [Key]
    public int GraduacaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}

public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }
    public int GraduacaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
    public virtual Graduacao Graduacao { get; set; }
}

public class Perfil
{
    [Key]
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

Então, um `select` básico ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id) 
{
    var resultados = context.Graduacoes
                        .Include(g => g.Cursos)
                        .Where(g => g.GraduacaoId == id).ToList();

    ViewBag.Graduacao = new SelectList(db.Graduacao, "Id", "Nome");

    return View(resultados);
}
```

`Perfil` deve ser carregado por carga preguiçosa, que é feita automaticamente pelo Entity Framework.

---

**EDIT**

Mude seu `Controller` para:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    ViewBag.Graduacao = new SelectList(db.Graduacao, "Id", "Nome");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pesquisa(int id) 
{
    var resultados = context.Graduacoes
                        .Include(g => g.Cursos)
                        .Where(g => g.GraduacaoId == id).ToList();

    ViewBag.Graduacao = new SelectList(db.Graduacao, "Id", "Nome");

    return View("Index", resultados);
}
```

View:

```
<div> 
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Pesquisa", "Graduacoes"))
     {

         <div class="form-group">
             @Html.DropDownList("Graduacoes")

         </div>

         <button type="submit" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Buscar</button>
     }
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a forma correta de fazer essa view? Meu model está assim como vc descreveu e o fiz a consulta. Só que quando clico em "Pesquisar" retorna o erro: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Competências.Models.Graduacao]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Competências.Models.Curso]'.

Comment: Bom, o erro é claro. A primeira linha da *View* tem que ser `@model IEnumberable<Competencias.Models.Graduacao>`, e não `@model IEnumberable<Competencias.Models.Curso>`.

Comment: Desculpa, não era essa o erro. é: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Graduacao'." apontando para meu dropdownlist que está "@Html.DropDownList("Graduacao")

Comment: O erro é porque tem uma declaração de `@Html.DropDownList` que não está sendo carregada corretamente. Experimente remover a declaração usando comentários `@* *@` e repita o teste.

Comment: Ele está carregando corretamente. Eu vejo as opções que eu quero na lista, escolho uma e ao pesquisar dá esse erro. Comentando a linha como vc pediu eu não visualizo o dropdownlist, só o botão pesquisar. E ao clicar nele, nada acontece.

Comment: Entendi. Na verdade é uma tela que lista os cursos baseado na graduação. Pode desfazer o comentário na DropDown. Vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Ta, estava usando duas actions com o mesmo nome e no seu exemplo vc colocou as duas numa só. ok, quando eu busco agora não dá erro, só não retorna nada. Eu tenho que inicializar o id não? (int id = 0)

Comment: Isso mesmo. O problema de inicializar o Id é que pode dar problema de ambiguidade no protótipo da `Action`. Melhor tratar o Id por dentro do método.

Comment: mas se eu não inicializar o id nem roda. Dá "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'" Deixei inicializado já. Tem algum problema na consulta. Não estou tendo retorno nenhum

Comment: Aí é só com debug.

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta passando model, controller e view. Pode dar uma olhada? Já tentei de tudo e não consigo retornar nada com a pesquisa

Comment: @PFVictor Ok, fico aguardando você.

Comment: Pronto Cigano, editado!

Comment: Eu estava usando uma view só. No caso essa que vc passou vai ser a Index certo?

Comment: @PFVictor Continua sendo uma View só, mas usando duas `Actions` em `Controller` para a lógica.